# Magento 2 pass argument in class from ui component

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, uicomponent, ui-form

I want to pass `boolean` argument to class method from `uicomponent_form.xml`

My xml code is

```
<field name="allow_shipping_method">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">myform</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">allow_shipping_method</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Allow Shipping Method</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

This is calling `public function toOptionArray($isActiveOnlyFlag = false)`     method of `Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods`.

There is anyway to pass argument?? is magento is providing such kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the checkout_index_index.xml the boolean passed as below,

```
<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```

Can you please try to use similar in your following code and try to access it in class.

```
<field name="allow_shipping_method">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">myform</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">allow_shipping_method</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Allow Shipping Method</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,Sam

Comment: Still all methods are coming, I have checked with both visible false & true.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your custom class over there and use :

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Namespace\Model;

    use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
    use \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config;

   class Method extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject 
         implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
   {
      /**
       * @var ScopeConfigInterface
       */
         protected $_scopeConfig;

      /**
       * @var Config
       */
         protected $_deliveryModelConfig;

      /**
       * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
       * @param Config    $deliveryModelConfig
       */
        public function __construct(
            ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            Config $deliveryModelConfig
        ) {

             $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
             $this->_deliveryModelConfig = $deliveryModelConfig;
         }

         public function toOptionArray()
         {
             $deliveryMethods = $this->_deliveryModelConfig->getActiveCarriers();
             $deliveryMethodsArray = array();
             foreach ($deliveryMethods as $shippigCode => $shippingModel) {
               $shippingTitle = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/title');
               $deliveryMethodsArray[$shippigCode] = array(
               'label' => $shippingTitle,
               'value' => $shippigCode
              );
             }
            return $deliveryMethodsArray;
          }
    }
```